# How can I get a specific element value of object in localstorage

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, local-storage

I'm trying to get **"city"** value (in case: Porto, Lisboa, Leiria, Londres) of **localstorage** and put It in a variable. I wish to do this in a **loop for** and use each city name in a function.

Now, I'm here:

```
Object.entries(localStorage).map(([id, valueJSON]) => {
  cityName = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('persist:root', 'allWeather', 'city')));
  console.log(cityName)
```

My return is this:

> {"allWeather":"[{"id":0.47266066302275545,"city":"Porto"},{"id":0.8669553925029849,"city":"Lisboa"},{"id":0.5502373167192611,"city":"Leiria"},{"id":0.19655712000371484,"city":"Londres"}]","_persist":"{"version":-1,"rehydrated":true}"}

How can I do this? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const cities = 
    // Parse the localstorage item to object
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('persist:root', 'allWeather', 'city'))
    // Get the allWeather property
    .allWeather
    // Get the city properties only
    .map(weather => weather.city);
```

Comment: Also, remember you need to stringify the object before saving it to localstorage

Answer (score 0):

- You need to convert the object string to JSON using `JSON.parse`
- `[{ city }]` this part is not right. Change it to `city`

Comment: Thanks Khánh for the help. It works for a part of my problems but still not working full.
I check typeof cidade, and this is an object. So I did this, but I get more than I expect:
const { allWeather: city } = cidade;
console.log(city) // [{"id": 0.8414362786063185,"city": "Porto"},{"id":0.06554569986423231,"city":"Lisbon"}]
I need just Porto. And after this, I would like to get all city values in a loop for (Porto, Lisbon...)